# Pascal Triangle Array

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to make a Pascal triangle using python arrays , i succeeded in doing so but in the output i get zeros in the usual blank spaces , i want to remove the zeros but i don't know how, there is my code :

```
n = int(input("range: "))
t = [([0] * n) for i in range(n)]
t[0][0] = 1
for i in range(1, n):
    t[i][0] = 1
    t[i][i] = 1
    for j in range(1, i):
        t[i][j] = t[i - 1][j] + t[i - 1][j - 1]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(t[i][j], end="")
    print("\n")
```

The output is :

> range: 5
>
> 10000
>
> 11000
>
> 12100
>
> 13310
>
> 14641

Comment: _I don't want to see the zeros.._ why dont you replace the zeroes with spaces or what ever you need

Comment: I don't know why there is zeros there in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input("range: "))
t = [([""] * n) for i in range(n)]
t[0][0] = 1
for i in range(1, n):
    t[i][0] = 1
    t[i][i] = 1
    for j in range(1, i):
        t[i][j] = t[i - 1][j] + t[i - 1][j - 1]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(t[i][j], end="")
    print("\n")
```